# SwiftUI: Get rid of extra space below Navigationbar

Tags: xcode, view, swiftui, space, navigationbar

I've got a problem, that I always get extra space below my navigationbar:
[Example of Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSRbd.png)

I used this Code in ContentView:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        NextView()
    }
}
```

And in NextView I got

```
var body: some View {
    VStack() {
        List{
            Text("Bla")
            Text("Bla")
        }
    }
}
```

So I dont have multiple NavigationViews inside each others. Hiding the Bar isnt an option either, since I want to put Titles there. If I change the displayMode to .inline I remove all the space between the list and my status bar and everything overlaps - so thats not an option either.
Thank you for any help!
Best regards!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean here by "everything overlaps." Setting displayMode to .inline is definitely what you're looking for (the default .large setting is creating the space you're talking about). Perhaps you've set `edgesIgnoringSafeAreas` somewhere in this stack?

Comment: Hey Rob, .inline makes the list go under the navigation bar. I still want to have that bar, but without the extra space. I want he bar and directly below it my list. But that doesnt happen. I already tried the edgesIgnoringSafeSpaces and I've tried to change the size of the bar - Nothing works (it has even no effect on the outcome)